# Session Timeout redirect in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So I'm having trouble getting a redirect to the login page when a session has timed out to work in Codeigniter. This is probably a really basic mistake on my part, but the code I'm using in my controller is:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
    redirect('login/');
}
```

It works as far as redirecting the user to the login page, but keeps looping back to the login page. Why is this?

Comment: I don't know CI but maybe you are executing that code in the login page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because there is no data in the session called `is_logged_in`. If you view the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), you will see the default data that is stored in the session:

> **What is Session Data?**
>
> A session, as far as CodeIgniter is concerned, is simply an array
>   containing the following information:
>
> The user's unique Session ID (this is a statistically random string
>   with very strong entropy, hashed with MD5 for portability, and
>   regenerated (by default) every five minutes) The user's IP Address The
>   user's User Agent data (the first 120 characters of the browser data
>   string) The "last activity" time stamp.

You need to either set `is_logged_in` when the user logs in or use something that is already in there like `session_id` or `last_activity`.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Thanks Stormdrain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the user is not on the login page. It sounds like it's executing whenever a request is made.

Something like this should do it:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') && !strstr(current_url(), 'login/')) {
    redirect('login/');
}
```

It could also be that, like stormdrain said, the session data isn't set.